# how to develop Android game UI

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx

i am pretty good in android but have not developed any games yet, and have no idea where to kick off.
I have idea of Game in my mind, but i have no idea how to convert that idea into game.
The most **big problem i am finding is building UI for that**, as i can build backend for the game with my logic but how to interact with games-UI that i new to me and have not done before.

Is there any tool or some kind of help by which i can easily build UI comonents for a game and use them easily in my game creation.

i had read about **libgdx** for android but i am not sure as using that i have to write code to display even a single point/entity.
Is there any nice, easy and fast way to develop game UI

**I have done starter RnD on google but still not much clear with GameUI creation.**

Any kind of guidance is appreciated.
Thanks 
Aj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of game is it?  2d / 3d graphics?  Or just text input (like a chance game or a quiz game?)

UI could mean many things.  To some people it's just the menu overlays and other interfaces, like health bars and the like.  To others UI is the entire rendering field.  Please clarify your terminology in this regard.

If you want to avoid as much code as possible there are libraries that can help.  Is there a way you can describe your game by analogy without giving away your secrets?  Then we can better assist you.

Comment: i need an interactive game to be developed

Answer (score 0):

The right place to ask would be in the gamedevs section of stackexchange, other than that it is a possible duplicate of / related to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/how-do-i-get-started-making-android-games